# Python fill missing entries in lists with full list

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list which represents the complete set:

```
complete_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

And a list  of lists (or numpy array) with rows which miss some items:

```
list_1 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
          ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
          ['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h']]
```

I would like to highlight the missing items with e.g. `N/A` like:

```
list_1 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'],
          ['N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
          ['a', 'b', 'c', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'g', 'h']]
```

Are there any built in solutions in numpy to achieve that? How would a pythonic solution look like? Currently, I fill an empty numpy array (the size is known beforehand) within two loops.

Answer (score 2):

With simple *membership test*:

```
complete_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
lst = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
          ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
          ['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h']]

res = [['N/A' if c not in sub_lst else c for c in complete_list]
       for sub_lst in lst]

print(res)
```

The output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A'], ['N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'g', 'h']]
```

Comment: Damn, why didn`t though of that. Very simple.

Comment: Note that for large sublists/complete lists, this would involve relatively expensive linear scans for each element. Assuming all the elements are hashable (`str`s are), changing `for sub_lst in lst` to `for sub_lst in map(frozenset, lst)` or something similar would reduce the cost per lookup from `O(n)` to `O(1)`, reducing the overall algorithm expense from `O(n²)` to `O(n)`. For small lists, as in this case, it won't matter, just a note in case your real code is working with hundreds or thousands of elements in the `complete_list`/`sub_lst`s.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, for small lists it doesn't show a significant speed up, but yes, I would consider that for large lists (if happened). If it's not just mapping on alphabet characters

Answer (score 1):

The main logic that can be implemented is:

```py
for lists in list_1:
    for i, x in enumerate(complete_list):
        try:
            if lists[i] != x:
                lists.insert(i,'N/A')
        except IndexError:
            lists.append('N/A')
```

But its time complexity is O(m*n). I am trying to reduce it.

**UPDATE :** After some modifications I am here with a little bit better solution. thats here:

```py
complete_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
complete_len = len(complete_list)

list_1 = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
          ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'],
          ['a', 'b', 'c', 'g', 'h']]

for list_ in list_1:             #for each list in list_1
    for i in range(complete_len):
        if list_[i] == complete_list[i]:
            if i != len(list_)-1:
                continue
            else:                #appends last elements and exit(case list_1[0])
                list_ += ['N/A']*(complete_len-len(list_))
                break
        else:
            list_.insert(i,'N/A')
            if len(list_) == complete_len:
                break

for list_ in list_1:
    print(list_)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A']
['N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'g', 'h']
```

Comment: The time complexity here is weird; the outer loop is `O(m)` (where `m` is the number of sublists, which is not intrinsically tied to the size of `complete_list`, so we need a different variable from `n`), and the inner loop is `O(n²)`, because is a `O(n)` loop over `complete_list`, where each loop does `O(n)` work for the `insert` (though the more inserts it needs to do, the cheaper each `insert` will be, because fewer elements need to be moved). It's clever, but the performance will be unusually variable based on inputs. Real big-O is `O(m * n²)` if I'm reading it correctly.

Comment: OH! I see it can be `O(m*n2)` in worst case. I am working on it

Comment: See I have edited this post. Can I further reduce the complexity if yes then please suggest me.